# Display \n characters as newlines when using tail?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface

I have a file that I am trying to read by using tail -f. I was wondering if there was a way to have the terminal output an actual line break instead of the \n character.

Comment: As a rule, tail -f will display line breaks as line breaks.

You may have an issue with your console settings, if that's what you're seeing.

Comment: Or he's tailing a file which actually has a literal \n in it. Maybe line breaks were converted to a literal "\n" before being written to a file.

Comment: Tip: if you would like colours and stuff, try: `grc --colour=on tail -f file | sed 's/\\n/\n░░░░/g`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
tail -f file | sed 's/\\n/\n/g'
```

Comment: I would like to add that I found I needed to actually physically enter a line break in my sed command after the back-slash in order to make this work, like so: `~$ tail -f /var/log/apache2/error_log | sed 's/\\n/\ > /g'`

Comment: Does anyone know of a way to achieve the same thing for multitail? Here's a question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239774/how-can-i-display-n-as-new-lines-in-multitail

Comment: I cannot get that to work as an alias in my .bashrc

Comment: @Kdansky: You didn't show how you defined the alias or what kind of problem you're having so I can only guess. One problem you may be having is with quoting. An extra backslash may help: `alias forward="tail -f file | sed 's/\\\n/\n/g'"`. If you want to be able to specify the filename as an argument, you should use a function instead of an alias: `forward () { tail -f "$@" | sed 's/\\n/\n/g'; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
tail -1 file | awk '{gsub(/\\n/,"")}1'
```